# I need to filter an array of object that contains an array of object

Tags: javascript

So here's my data, I need to reduce? or filter it based on the given search string.

```js
const contents = [
  {
    title: "Accounts",
    links: [
      {
        header: "Accounts by Status",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Executions",
    links: [
      {
        header: "Purchase and Sales",
      },
      {
        header: "AMLA Transactions Proof List",
      },
      {
        header: "Account Ranking",
      },
      {
        header: "Trading Summary",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const search = "account";

console.log(
  contents.filter((content) =>
    content.links.some((link) =>
      link.header.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    )
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction? I think reduce with filter can do the job but I don't know where to start. Thanks!

If my search string is 'account'
My desired output should be something like this

```js
[{
    title: 'Accounts',
    links: [{
      header: 'Accounts by Status'
    }]
  },
  {
    title: 'Executions',
    links: [{
      header: 'Account Ranking'
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: you only want to filter the header in links? what'll happen if i search "Trading"?

Comment: So does your current "solution" work or not? I'm confused because you call it a solution and then ask where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rebuild `content` with links, if they match.

```js
const
    contents = [{ title: 'Accounts', links: [{ header: 'Accounts by Status' }] }, { title: 'Executions', links: [{ header: 'Purchase and Sales' }, { header: 'AMLA Transactions Proof List' }, { header: 'Account Ranking' }, { header: 'Trading Summary' }] }], 
    search = 'account',
    result = contents.flatMap(content => {
        const links = content.links.filter(({ header }) => header
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(search.toLowerCase())
        );
        return links.length
            ? { ...content, links }
            : [];
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution filters the links array by search string, and if non is found removes the item all together. The test input contains one more item that produces no hit: `{ title: 'No hit', links: [{ header: 'Something else' }] }`

```js
const input = [
  { title: 'Accounts', links: [{ header: 'Accounts by Status' }] },
  { title: 'Executions', links: [{ header: 'Purchase and Sales' }, { header: 'AMLA Transactions Proof List' }, { header: 'Account Ranking' }, { header: 'Trading Summary' }] },
  { title: 'No hit', links: [{ header: 'Something else' }] }
];
const searchString = 'account';

// for performance perform lowercase once ahead of time:
const search = searchString.toLowerCase();
const result = input.map(obj => {
  let arr = obj.links.filter(o => o.header.toLowerCase().includes(search));
  if(arr.length) {
    // don't change original input, but return a filtered copy
    return {
      title: obj.title,
      links: arr
    };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}).filter(Boolean);
console.log(result);
```